# I cannot insert data into database

Tags: php, sql

I have checked all table and column names are right and there are no mistakes in any input names but it is not inserting that data.

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['Murad'])){
  session_start();
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$userName=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['pwd1'];
$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "123";
$mysql_databse = "websiteusersa";
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysqli_select_db($bd,'websiteusersa');
$sql = "INSERT INTO websiteusersa
       (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
       VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')";
$query = mysqli_query($bd, $sql); 
header("location: main.php?/$firstname/");
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to output your raw SQL query (with bounded values) and execute it directly in CLI (or PhpMyAdmin)?

By the way, be careful to use prepare method of mysqli (or better PDO) to avoid SQL injection. Your code here is vulnerable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity try "$query = mysqli_query($bd, $sql) or die(mysql_error())" to see if there's something misconstrued. You can also add that to mysql_connect. Consider using the PDO o CLI API for this.

Comment: You code is not secured,it's appealing towards sql injections. Study [PHP sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and try to get the query value first in MysqlWorkbench or PhpMyAdmin.
Then try to print your `$sql` value in the browser first,see if it's giving proper results

Answer (score 2):

You can post a question here but not check for error messages?

```
$query = mysqli_query($bd, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
                                    ^
```

Its a simple debugging process which others have to perform for you then. That will simply tell you where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Check your statement here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO websiteusersa
   (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
   VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')";
```

maybe  the column **fullname** could possibly mean **firstname** that's why your code doesn't work.